# PHP class Libmemcached not found

Tags: php, apache, memcached, libmemcached

I am transferring a PHP application 9running on apache) from Centos to Ubuntu. When I deploy the code on Ubuntu I get an error "Class Libmemcached not found".

When I compare phpinfo pages, I can see that the Centos one has "libmemcached" section, while the Ubuntu one has "memcached" section.

On both systems phpinfo has "memcache" (no "d" in the end) section.

It looks like my Centos PHP has "libmemcached" extension and my Ubuntu PHP doesn't. How can I download that extension? Or can I somehow just transfer the extension from my Centos system?

I found php-libmemcached repository on github ( https://github.com/kajidai/php-libmemcached ), that might be what I am looking for, but I don't know how to install it on Ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: Is it not in the apt repositories youre currently using? (i think its `php5-memcached`)?

Comment: php5-memcached has memcached extension. The memcached extension doesn't have class Libmemcached that my app uses

Comment: did you see if there was `php5-libmemcached` either in your current sources or as a ppa?

Comment: No, couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The `libmemcached` extension you are using isn't an official extension. I don't know were Centos get it from.

So I recommend to use/install the official `memcached` extension from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached)
and update your application.

Else you have to install the `libmemcached` extension from scratch with the following steps:

- download from [github](https://github.com/kajidai/php-libmemcached)
- unpack the file
- go into the new folder
- `phpize`
- `./configure`
- `make install`
- enable it within you `php.ini`
- restart you webserver